# Transform XSLT attributes to elements

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform my XML. I have been able to get it partly working, but i can not get it right

I have included what i have been able to get to work, and what i am trying to get the final output to look like. Any help would be great.  I have checked multiple searches and have only got it to work kinda of.

Current Output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objects>
  <object><class>fhwed8885_notices</class><name>notices</name>
    <property><name>DocumentInformation</name>
      <object><class>fhwed8885_DocumentInformation</class><name>DocumentInformation</name>
        <property><name>DocId</name><value>510047</value></property>
        <property><name>GenerationType</name><value>pdf</value></property>
        <property><name>ReqId</name><value>aaa12345-555435d-ggaade5</value></property>
        <property><name>FilePath</name><value>missing</value></property>
      </object>
    </property>
    <property><name>PNAME</name>
      <object><class>fhwed8885_PNAME</class><name>PNAME</name>
        <property><name>NAME</name><value>JOHN KINGHT</value></property>
        <property><name>ADDR01</name><value>1896 KELLER SPRINGS</value></property>
        <property><name>ADDR02</name><value></value></property>
        <property><name>ADDR03</name><value></value></property>
        <property><name>ADDR04</name><value>ADDISON, TX 75181-0000</value></property>
      </object>
    </property>
  </object>
</objects>
```

XML Input:

```
<objects>
    <object class="fhwed8885_notices" name="notices">
        <property name="DocumentInformation">
            <object class="fhwed8885_DocumentInformation" name="DocumentInformation">
                <property name="DocId" value="510047"/>
                <property name="GenerationType" value="pdf"/>
                <property name="ReqId" value="aaa12345-555435d-ggaade5"/>
                <property name="FilePath" value="missing"/>
            </object>
        </property>
        <property name="PNAME">
            <object class="fhwed8885_PNAME" name="PNAME">
                <property name="NAME" value="JOHN KINGHT"/>
                <property name="ADDR01" value="1896 KELLER SPRINGS"/>
                <property name="ADDR02" value=""/>
                <property name="ADDR03" value=""/>
                <property name="ADDR04" value="ADDISON, TX 75181-0000"/>
            </object>
        </property>
    </object>
</objects>
```

XSLT Transform:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        <xsl:element name="{name()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<notices>
    <DocumentInformation>
        <DocId>510047</DocId>
        <GenerationType>pdf</GenerationType>
        <ReqId>aaa12345-555435d-ggaade5</ReqId>
        <ReqFilePath>missing</ReqFilePath>
    </DocumentInformation>
    <PNAME>
        <NAME>JOHN KINGHT</NAME>
        <ADDR01>1896 KELLER SPRINGS</ADDR01>
        <ADDR02/>
        <ADDR03/>
        <ADDR04>ADDISON, TX 75181-0000</ADDR04>
    </PNAME>
</notices>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following transformation should do it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


  <xsl:template match="*[@name]">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <!-- Skip elements that have a child that has the same value for @name-->
  <xsl:template match="*[@name=child::*/@name]" priority="2">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@name|@class"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: What does `<xsl:template match="@name|@class"/>` do??

Answer (score 1):

**This is the shortest so far (just one template, 11 lines) solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="object[@name] | property[not(object)][@name]">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided source XML document**:

```
<objects>
    <object class="fhwed8885_notices" name="notices">
        <property name="DocumentInformation">
            <object class="fhwed8885_DocumentInformation" name="DocumentInformation">
                <property name="DocId" value="510047"/>
                <property name="GenerationType" value="pdf"/>
                <property name="ReqId" value="aaa12345-555435d-ggaade5"/>
                <property name="FilePath" value="missing"/>
            </object>
        </property>
        <property name="PNAME">
            <object class="fhwed8885_PNAME" name="PNAME">
                <property name="NAME" value="JOHN KINGHT"/>
                <property name="ADDR01" value="1896 KELLER SPRINGS"/>
                <property name="ADDR02" value=""/>
                <property name="ADDR03" value=""/>
                <property name="ADDR04" value="ADDISON, TX 75181-0000"/>
            </object>
        </property>
    </object>
</objects>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<notices>
   <DocumentInformation>
      <DocId>510047</DocId>
      <GenerationType>pdf</GenerationType>
      <ReqId>aaa12345-555435d-ggaade5</ReqId>
      <FilePath>missing</FilePath>
   </DocumentInformation>
   <PNAME>
      <NAME>JOHN KINGHT</NAME>
      <ADDR01>1896 KELLER SPRINGS</ADDR01>
      <ADDR02/>
      <ADDR03/>
      <ADDR04>ADDISON, TX 75181-0000</ADDR04>
   </PNAME>
</notices>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[@name]">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is not exactly identical to the one you show - but I don't know which one of the double headings should be removed.

Note also that this assumes that the root `objects` element has only one `object` child. Otherwise the result will be an XML fragment, not a well-formed XML document.